# Send array to next viewcontroller iOs xcode

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, arrays, xcode4.5

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Passing Data between View Controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers)

I have 2 view controller:

1. Index
2. Second

In Index I have 2 `textfield` and `button`.

I fill this text field and press "next button" to second view, I need to "show" this two text field, by using Array (later I will send JSON data).
How I can best realize? Please help!
Best regards
Ivan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare an `@property` in class `Second` as `textArray`. And then while pushing to `Second` from `Index`, you need to set this property.

In `Second.h` file,

```
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSArray *textArray;
```

In `Index.m` file,

```
Second *aSecond = [[Second alloc] init];
aSecond.textArray = @[textField1.text, textField2.text];
//write code to push from Index to Second
```

Now in class `Second`, you can use it as `aSecond.textArray[0]` and `aSecond.textArray[1]`